# Make a spell checker

Tags: vb.net

I am a newbie to VB.Net. Before, I did programming in PHP. I made a spell checker in PHP which splitted a big string into single word by spaces, checked if the word is there in the dictionary, if not, it highlighted it and gave some suggestions when a user clicks on it. I want to make the same thing in VB.Net... Any ideas??

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe [NHunspell](http://nhunspell.sourceforge.net/) helps?

Answer (score 3):

make use of a Dictionnary(Of String, String) for your dictionnary. ;
To split the string, you have the Split function (" ,;.") ;
define ExtWord, a class holding the word, a boolean stating if in or not the dictionnary,
and the proposed corrections. 
Then you have a list of ExtWord that you bind to a ListView, the
listview having a Horizontal WrapPanel as ItemsPanel.
Set the background color of TextBlock depending if inside the Dictionnary or not .
Then handle the right click on a TextBlock, and can build a ContextMenu in code and add the correct words inside it in code, then show it.

Only problem i see is how to do the 'carriage return' with
the WrapPanel.

Hopes it helps to get to your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try below link for spell checker in vb.net

http://www.a1vbcode.com/app-3641.asp

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/265823/i00-VB-NET-Spell-Check-No-3rd-Party-Components-Req

Comment: the second one is  very advanced.... i am just a beginner... i don't know how to use this in my project... Would you please help me.. Or can you give any another solution...?

Comment: download the project and run the visual studio

Comment: you are full fresher in .net?